# Docker: Looks something went wrong in step Looking for vboxmanage.exe

Tags: docker, virtualbox

I just installed Docker Toolbox on my windows 7 machine.
After installing I run the Docker Quickstart terminal which displays the following message:

Looks something went wrong in step nLooking for vboxmanage.exen... Press any key to continue....

Anyone here who knows how to solve this?

Regards,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solved the problem by cleaning my .bashrc file.
More specific, i removed the cd , which makes perfectly sense.

Comment: To be more specific, if you used git bash in the past and have set a default path (so git opens in your project path each time) you like have a .bashrc file with a line like this

cd ../../PATH/TO/MY-DIR/

This line is what is causing the problem for Docker quick start. Just open the file and delete the line and run the docker quick start again.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, where is this file? @GlenF.

Comment: Mine was in the root user directory.

Answer (score 47):

The same thing happened to me. At this moment I am using Windows Home.

At least in my case, what happened was that the environment variables **DOCKER_MACHINE** and **DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH** were not created for the system.

I just had to add them and it worked.

[image]

Comment: docker_machine shouldn't be needed, it is derived from D_T_I_P

Comment: yes, it's worked for me because i had already installed virtualbox.

Comment: For me, on Windows 10 Home, even after adding the environment variables, it didn't work. After running Docker Quickstart Terminal as an administrator, it worked right away.

Comment: Ensure you run it with elevated privilages.

Answer (score 18):

For me, the problem was that the `DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALLPATH` was only set for the user used to escalate `priviligies` at installation. When I run `Docker Quickstart` as my regular user, the `DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALLPATH` variable is empty, producing the error.
Setting `DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALLPATH` system wide solved the problem.

Answer (score 14):

I'm Windows 8.1 user, I got the same problem when I installing the Docker Toolbox.

Because I have a previous version of VirtualBox installed, so I uncheck the VirtualBox install option in the Docker Toolbox installer.

After the install and I run `Docker Quickstart terminal` and get the same problem **looks like something went wrong in step 'looking for vboxmanage.exe'**.

Look at the file `D:\Docker Toolbox\start.sh`, there are some code fragment：

```
STEP="Looking for vboxmanage.exe"
if [ ! -z "$VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH" ]; then
  VBOXMANAGE="${VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH}VBoxManage.exe"
else
  VBOXMANAGE="${VBOX_INSTALL_PATH}VBoxManage.exe"
fi
```

The start.sh use `$VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH` and `${VBOX_INSTALL_PATH}` Environment Variables to locate the VBoxManage.exe.

And I find my system variables `VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH` is

```
D:\VirtualBox
```

and then, I change it to

```
D:\VirtualBox\
```

**It works fine!**

Or maybe you miss the `VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH`/`VBOX_INSTALL_PATH`  Environment Variables.

This is my first answer on stackoverflow, I hope this will help you! Finally forgive my poor english ):

Answer (score 12):

For me, it helped to start Docker Quickstart Terminal with admin privileges.

Answer (score 10):

This works if you do not have admin rights:

```
> Setx DOCKER_MACHINE "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe"
> Setx DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\\"
> Setx VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\\"
```

The double backslash in the end makes sure that the variable is saved with one backslash as last character, needed in `C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh`:

```
> echo %DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH%
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\
```

Answer (score 5):

Running docker as Administrator solved the problem for me.

Comment: Admin user or put the variable under System variable would do the work.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.
Inside your toolbox installation folder you should be able to find the **installers folder**, there you'll find a setup.exe for a Oracle Virtual Box. Double click it, install it and you should be able to reopen the Docker Quickstart with no problems.
Hope this helps!
Cheers! :D

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution:  I thought I could just double click on it, but instead need to bring up a windows command prompt, CD to C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox , and type

> sh start.sh

Answer (score 4):

Due to the relative `DOCKER_MACHINE` path definition on [L10](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/7e92244d7497ecd432ed71ad5381a4c0ff56e02a/windows/start.sh#L10), it seems that `start.sh` will only run when you are inside its directory. I fixed it by modifying the target of the "Docker Quickstart Terminal" shortcut as follows:

```
C:\Tools\Git\git-bash.exe -c "cd /c/tools/docker; ./start.sh"
```

Substitute the paths to GitBash and Docker Toolbox to match your installations. If your paths contain spaces, be sure to wrap them in quotes as usual. For example:

```
"C:\Tools\Git Bash\git-bash.exe" -c "cd '/c/tools/docker toolbox'; ./start.sh"
```

For context, I had GitBash and VirtualBox already installed before installing Docker Toolbox, so I deselected those options during its install. I'm sure that if I went with the default options, this issue wouldn't have happened. That's probably why some folks on GitHub suggest uninstalling VirtualBox and re-installing Docker Toolbox. Don't do that, it's almost certainly unnecessary.

Comment: ^ This. A neat solution and doesn't involve mucking with your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know how good an open-source program is?
You can actually investigate the issue yourselve, which could be way more precise.

1. please scroll the quickstart terminal up and see which error message you have got
   [image]
2. open C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh (Where you install docker toolbox) with text editer, e.g. sublime text
   and see the codes
3. if it is in step "looking for vboxmange.exe", it should be before STEP="Checking if machine $VM exists" and there are only 50 lines to read
4. As of 2018-11-27, the only two error that could be given in this step is from these lines, so investigate and find your error in it:

which are:

```
if [ ! -f "${DOCKER_MACHINE}" ]; then
      echo "Docker Machine is not installed. Please re-run the Toolbox Installer and try again."
      exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f "${VBOXMANAGE}" ]; then
      echo "VirtualBox is not installed. Please re-run the Toolbox Installer and try again."
      exit 1
fi
```

In which:

```
DOCKER_MACHINE="${DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH}\docker-machine.exe"
```

And

```
if [ ! -z "$VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH" ]; then
  VBOXMANAGE="${VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH}VBoxManage.exe"
else
  VBOXMANAGE="${VBOX_INSTALL_PATH}VBoxManage.exe"
fi
```

So, check your environmental variables and echo it.

In my case, the reason is that DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH is an admin user variable:
[image]

So, run the quickstart terminal as admin user or put the variable under System variable would do the work

Answer (score 2):

I personally solved this issue by adding the following property to my env (Windows Env variables):

```
DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\
```

as pointed out by the `start.sh` script of the Docker Toolbox installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this reinstalling the VirtualBox, choosing **repair** mode.
**C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\installers\virtualbox** -> **virtualbox.exe**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Ya0.png)
After finished the process, restart you machine and smile!

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7 users:
Change value "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\" to "C:\Progra~1\Oracle\VirtualBox\" for **VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH** system variable in environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running docker from admin cmd then just try to scroll up and you will get the error message, and then you can solve the issue.

For me the the error "Docker Machine is not installed. Please re-run the Toolbox Installer and try again."
But unfortunately reinstall did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem on Win 10 Home and I tried probably every solution from this topic but nothing works, only thing that worked for me was hardcoding Path to VBOX in start.sh.
So in start.sh in this part:

```
STEP="Looking for vboxmanage.exe"
if [ ! -z "$VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH" ]; then
  VBOXMANAGE="${VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH}VBoxManage.exe"
else
  VBOXMANAGE="${VBOX_INSTALL_PATH}VBoxManage.exe"
fi
```

I did this:

```
STEP="Looking for vboxmanage.exe"
if [ ! -z "$VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH" ]; then
  VBOXMANAGE="C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe"
else
  VBOXMANAGE="${VBOX_INSTALL_PATH}VBoxManage.exe"
fi
```

And this works very well.
I know that this solution(hardcoding path) isn't best possible but it's only one which worked for me, and I think that sometimes it's better to use bad solution which works than good one which didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the user connects to some sort of secured networks using VPN, TLS machine certs gets messed up, upon restarting machine and regenerating TLS machine certs,  docker toolbox is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.XX.XX

Answer (score 0):

In windows 8.1, I solved the problem by **just adding extra** `\` to the `DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH` environment variable.

Installer has created the user variable for admin as `DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox`
, but it should be

```
DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\
```

Answer (score 0):

For people that installed docker with chocolatey you need to install VirtualBox separately from docker with `choco install virtualbox` and set environment variables as this

```
DOCKER_MACHINE == "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe"
DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH == "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\"
VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH == "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"
```

don't forget to add `\` at the end of the folders

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue on my Windows 7 machine and below steps has resolved the same

1. Went to C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\installers\virtualbox and doubleclick virtualbox.msi to install Oracle Virtual box. **(Note : It will install andd ask permission for 3-4 more components, Grant them all)**
2. Set up the Env Variables
   **DOCKER_MACHINE C:\Program Files\Docker** Toolbox\docker-machine.exe
   **DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH** C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox
3. Restart the machine
4. Finally Open **Docker Quickstart Terminal** and give it some minutes (probably 5-10) to let it do the setup

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same issue with the vboxmanage.exe upon running my docker toolbox.

I managed to solve the problem by installing virtualbox since I did not install virtualbox on my computer.

Might as well give it a try.

Answer (score -3):

Docker Tool Box is not a standalone application. It has many other tools like Oracle Virtual Box, Git & docker engine itself.

`./start.sh` is seeking some existing configuration which might miss in the older version. I updated the GIT version from `2.0.x` to `2.12.x` & it works for me.